# rss feed into custom browser activity instead of normal browser

Tags: android

So I have my browser activity ready, however I'm struggling to get the code working to open the link from my rss feed to open in that, it just goes to a blank page. I have tried numerous things but nothing is working. So I have ended up going back to standard code as used in this tutorial http://www.itcuties.com/android/how-to-write-android-rss-parser/ . I am using the engadget feed as an example to see if i could get it working. Here is my listlistener activity

```
    public class ListListener implements OnItemClickListener {
// List item's reference
List<RssItem> listItems;
// Calling activity reference
Activity activity;

public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
listItems = aListItems;
activity = anActivity;
}

/**
* Start a browser with url from the rss item.
*/
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));

activity.startActivity(i);

}

}
```

and here is my engadgetfeed activity

```
public class EngadgetFeed extends Activity {

private EngadgetFeed local;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_engadget_feed);
// Set reference to this activity
local = this;

GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

// Start download RSS task
task.execute("http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml");

// Debug the thread name
Log.d("Engadget", Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
@Override
protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

// Debug the task thread name
Log.d("Engadget", Thread.currentThread().getName());

try {
// Create RSS reader
RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

// Parse RSS, get items
return rssReader.getItems();

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Engadget", e.getMessage());
}

return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

// Get a ListView from main view
ListView endgadgetfeed = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

// Create a list adapter
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>          (local,R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
// Set list adapter for the ListView
endgadgetfeed.setAdapter(adapter);

// Set list view item click listener
endgadgetfeed.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
}
}


}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what I had to do, and i'm over the moon for answering my own question, is the following;

**instead of having the following**:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));

    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```

**I used this**:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Uri uri;
    String stringuri;
    stringuri = (Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink())).toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(activity, Browser2.class);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, stringuri);

    activity.startActivity(i);              
}
```

So I hope this helps others who have the same.